# Calculate and add values to a data-frame

Tags: r

My dataset looks like this:

```
"userid","progress"
1, incomplete
2, complete
3, not attempted
4, incomplete
5, not attempted
6, complete
7, complete
8, complete
9, complete
10, incomplete
```

I want to make a pie chart showing the percentage of people who have status-completed, incomplete and not attempted, that is `total no of users/user id = complete/incomplete`

This code is not working.

```
var1 = nrow(data1)/sum(data1$progress=="complete")
var2 = nrow(data1)/sum(data1$progress=="incomplete")

  df <- data.frame(
    val = c (var1, var2)

  )

  hchart(df, "pie")%>%hc_add_series_labels_values(values = df)
```

Comment: Can you make the input data into a format that is easy to paste (e.g. using `dput`)? Also, make sure you specify all the non-base packages you're using to plot your data.

Comment: Seems strange that you are trying to do `total rows / rows where progress is "complete"`. Normally you'd want `total rows` in the denominator.

Comment: @Gregor oh yes, my bad!

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to make a pie chart, most methods will do much of the work for you. No need to explicitly calculate the percentages. Anyway, the output of `table` is exactly what you want together with `pie`

```
# Load your data
ds <- read.csv(header = TRUE, text = 
"userid,progress
1, incomplete
2, complete
3, not attempted
4, incomplete
5, not attempted
6, complete
7, complete
8, complete
9, complete
10, incomplete")

# Tabularize
tab <- table(ds$progress)
pie(tab) # Make piechart
```

[image]

As you see below, `table` counts the number of appearances for each level and returns a named `integer` vector. The nice thing here is that `pie()` computes the angles/areas from the relative frequencies and uses the names to label the chart.

```
print(tab)
#
#      complete     incomplete  not attempted 
#             5              3              2
```

If you insist on computing the percentages yourself, you can just use `tab/sum(tab)`.

**Edit:** I see that you try to use the **highcharter** package. Why not use `hcpie` in that case? That function takes a factor as input:

```
library("highcharter")
hcpie(ds$progress)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
userid <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
progress <- c("incomplete","complete", "not attempted", "incomplete", "not attempted", "complete","complete","complete", "complete","incomplete")
df <- data.frame("userid"=userid, "progress"=progress)
df$progress <- as.factor(df$progress)
var1 = nrow(df[which(df$progress=="complete"), ])/nrow(df)
var2 = nrow(df[which(df$progress=="incomplete"), ])/nrow(df) 
var3 = nrow(df[which(df$progress=="not attempted"), ])/nrow(df) 
data <- c(var1, var2, var3)
pie(data, labels=c("complete","incomplete", "not attempted"))
```